# Change <a> download atrribute value trough javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, download

I am trying to change an `<a>` tag download attribute value with the input from a user.

The user should be able to enter the file name and then click download. I have searched all over and cannot seem to find the answer. Can you please give me some advice?

HTML:

```
 <input id="filename" type="text" onChange="inputChange(event)"/>

 <a download="RENAME-ME.csv" href="#" class="download">
       Download your file
 </a>
```

Javascript:

```
function inputChange(e) {
   console.log(document.getElementById("filename").value);
}
```

Comment: The `href` attribute is `#`, so nothing is going to happen when you click that link anyway. It's not clear what behavior you are trying to elicit here.

Comment: This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/2wz5zs7r/) shows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like this:

```
$('#filename').on('input', function() { 
   document.getElementsByClassName("download")[0].download = document.getElementById("filename").value
   console.log("File name:" + document.getElementsByClassName("download")[0].download )
});
```

You can find the find the fiddle at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biogenetix/a7mfojka/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=a7mfojka)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input id="filename" type="text" onChange="inputChange(event)"/>
<a download="RENAME-ME.csv" href="#" class="download" id="button">
   Download your file
</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function inputChange(event){
    var filename = event.target.value;
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.setAttribute('download',  filename);
}
```